# How to convert following list having numbers as string into integer and float

Tags: python

```
t = ["3.4","7","","-1.3","-5",""]
```

How to convert this list into integer and float for further ananlysis?

I have done this so far but i got error.

```
t = ["3.4","7","","-1.3","-5",""]

def integer_float(string):
    try:
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return float(string)

for i in t:
    integer_float(i)
```

I got the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: What do you expect to be the result of converting `""` to a number?

Comment: Actually i imported that from a txt file and after importing everything becomes a string and there are some empty row as well. How to analyse such data. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you can't parse empty string as int nor float. try:

```
int(string or "0")
```

Comment: Thank you, It helped a lot.